# Who is working right now? (coronoavirus)

Tags: industrial-organisation, unemployment, covid-19-crisis

Is there any research, graphs, or any formal (non-opinion) information on where I can get information on what people are working right now? I want to know, who is still collecting a paycheck.

I am a sales representative that sells knives, and does virtual appointments online (over the phone, video conference, etc.), but I really need to show people that are *working*. So, I imagine police and hospitals are working right through this coronavirus (COVID-19), but someone who works in the party industry in Las Vegas are probably OUT of work, as their jobs are not essentials, and aid in the spreading of the virus.

So, instead of being "I assume" or "I guess" these people are working, what are the statistics of who is working right now? Where can I find them? When I google "people working right now" or "people working coronavirus", I guess a bunch of unrelated news, saying "the affects of working at home", which is useless.

Comment: *current* data are hard to come by, but data are available with a short lag— so in early April, you can look here: https://www.bls.gov/ces/tables/home.htm#ee

Comment: Eliter.  Did the answer provided help?

Comment: Mike J, it was kinda hard to navigate the bureau of labor statistics website, thanks for checking up on me!

Comment: Statistical agencies websites tend to be difficult to go through at times and depending on the data.    If this was not the answer you are looking for please clarify.    Thanks.  ADP (http://www.adpemploymentreport.com/) is also another source but also have a short lag.

Comment: you can always call the agency for additional help.

Answer (score 1):

Data on employment usually comes out a month or two (sometimes a year) after the reference period.   The Bureau of Labor Statistics (https://www.bls.gov/) puts out data on employment (who is working right now)  but to see the effects of our current crisis will take time to show.

Here are some links to the employment data that the BLS produces:

National employment (monthly):  https://www.bls.gov/ces/

State and local employment (monthly): https://www.bls.gov/sae/

State and county quarterly employment:  https://www.bls.gov/cew/

JOLTS data or Unemployment claims data can show you jobs that are hiring, laying off, separations,  and how many are collecting unemployment claims.  This could give you an idea about how many people are out of a job.

Job Openings and Labor Turnover Survey (monthly): https://www.bls.gov/jlt/data.htm

Unemployment Insurance Weekly Claims Data (weekly) : https://oui.doleta.gov/unemploy/claims.asp